# Method not found when calling a WebMethod

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

Service:

```
   public string Create(RestRegist objname)
   {
       RestRegist objrest = new RestRegist();
       return objrest.Create(objname);

   }
```

IService

[OperationContract]

```
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
        UriTemplate = "/AddData")]
        string AddCreate(RestRegist objname);
```

Web Config:

```
<services>
  <service name="SampleRestReg.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviour">
    <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="SampleRestReg.IService1" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviour" ></endpoint>
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://mylocalhost/Service1.svc"/>
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ServiceBehaviour">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ServiceBehaviour">
      <webHttp/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
```

my html page

Ajax code:

```
   $("#btnsave").click(function () {
       var name = $("#patient").val();
       var age = $("#Ag").val();
       var gender = $("#gender").val();
       var address = $("#ad1").val();
       var city = $('#city').val();
       var mobile = $('#phn').val();
       var depart = $('#Select2').val();
       var doctor = $('#Select3').val();

       $.ajax({
           Type: "POST",
           processData: true,
           dataType: "json",
           url: "http://localhost:51341/Service1.svc/AddData",
           data: '{ PatientName: "name", Age: "age", Gender:"gender", Address1:"address", City:"city", Phone:"mobile", Department: "depart", Doctor:"doctor" }',
           contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
           success: function (data, status, jqXHR) {
               alert('Record Save Successfully')
           },
           error: function (xhr) {
               alert(xhr.responseText);
           }
       });

   });

        </script>
```

This is my html page and ajax code,

im getting method not found ,when i hit save button, iam using Rest wcf service

I tried everything but no use..plz help me out

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title

Answer (score 0):

I guess this line needs some parameters.

In your javascript fill in those parameters according to the controls in your HTML.

```
var name = ...;
...

data: '{ PatientName: ''' + name
      + ''', Age: ' + age
      + ', Gender: ' + gender
      + ', Address1: '''
      + address + ''', City: '''
      + city + ''', Phone: '''
      + mobile + ''', Department: '''
      + depart + ''', Doctor: ''' + doctor
      + ''' }'
```

Comment: @sam: I missed the quotes. Can you try again?

Comment: we need to config IIS for this

Comment: @sam: I don't get your comment. Did my answer help?

Comment: :I did but Still stuck with that

Comment: i didnt configure IIS ,is that the reason .im not getting

Comment: Did you try the answer of tontonGG? If that doesn't help, I'm not sure what the reason is. I do know you need to add my code to get it to work. Maybe there are other issues I can't see now too.

Answer (score 0):

I have some experience with WCF Service in REST practise.
Can you access `http://yourlocalhost/Service1.svc/jsdebug` ? If you can't access this proxy, you have a first problem of javascript proxy generation... If so on see below :

In the web.config, behavior.endpointbehavior section can you try to add this tag

```
<behaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="YourBehaviorName">
            <webHttp />
            <enableWebScript />
        </behavior>
    <endpointBehaviors>
<behaviors>
```

Good luck ! Not easy starting with this stuff.

Comment: how to debug .jsdebug,im new to this plz help me out

Comment: i use this abv code,but getting "Endpoints using 'UriTemplate' cannot be used  with 'System.ServiceModel.Description.WebScriptEnablingBehavior'.

Comment: You cannot use the UriTemplate feature with enablescript.
You have to remove UriTemplate in WebMethod attribute.
Why did you remove from your original post the C# part code ?

Comment: Can you now access to jsdebug file ? I don't see <enableWebScript /> in your behavior after you update code ?

Comment: just check my Ajax code,if i call ajax, im getting "method not found".I have check for GET method its working fine,but im using POST.